# Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog 2.1.9 was not found

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, nuget

When attempting to add a NuGet reference to Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Orders, version 2.1.5, I get the following error:

```
NU1603: Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Availability 2.1.3 depends on Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog (>= 2.1.9) but Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog 2.1.9 was not found. An approximate best match of Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog 2.1.10 was resolved.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for '<MyProjectName>'.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to add the Catalog plugin (at version 2.1.10) separately. Then you can add Orders (at 2.1.5) without issue.

Comment: Wondering if there is a NuGet setting that would make this behavior automatic?